# Are my samples dependent or independent?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

I have an assignment where I have  car brands (Honda, Hyundai, Audi etc..), category (sportscar,hatchback, convertible etc..) and brand type(electric, non-electric). I want to determine the probability of having the Hyundai car given that it is a sportscar and electric.

I was thinking to use the formula:
P (A/B) where B is composite (sportscar and electric)
So i think i need: 
P(A|B∩C)=P(A∩B∩C) / P(B∩C)

But i am struggling with determining whether the events are independent. Could anyone help me with this? I thought they are dependent because they are all cars and probably having a sportscar affects the chances of it being electric or not but maybe my logic is wrong.
Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the math goes, if you treat them as independent when they are not, then you will end up with the wrong answer.  But if you treat them as dependent when they are independent, then the math will work out correctly anyways.  So the best approach is to treat them as dependent unless you have strong evidence otherwise.

If you are starting from a data set with all the information, then your probability is just the count of how many cars meet the conditions of A and B and C divided by the count of the number of cars that meet conditions B and C.